# Functions from a set of numbers to a set of letters?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Say I have two sets, $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B = \{a, b, c\}$. I know how to find regular functions with all numbers however how do I find a function that is $f: A\to B$?

Answer (score 2):

Your function will $f$ will be a subset of $A \times B$ such that $(x,y), (x, z) \in f$ implies $y = z$ and also $\{x \in A : \exists y(y \in B \; and \; (x, y) \in f)\} = A$. Example : $f = \{(1, a), (2, b), (3, c)\}$ or $f = \{(1, a), (2, a), (3, a)\}$ (if you don't want it to be bijection).

Comment: You also need to require that its domain is $A$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila sure thank you

Answer (score 1):

Functions are not necessarily given by formulas with addition, or sine and exponentiation.

Functions are just collections of ordered pairs, which satisfy a certain property. When we write $f\colon A\to B$ we mean to say that:

1. $f$ is a collection of ordered pairs $\langle a,b\rangle$ such that $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.
2. For every $a\in A$ there is exactly one ordered pair $\langle a,b\rangle$ in $f$. Then we can say that such $b$ is $f(a)$.

In small sets you can just write, instead of ordered pairs, the values that $f$ returns. For example, $f(1)=1,f(2)=3,f(3)=1$ is a function from $A$ to itself. You can use a similar way to write down a function from $A$ to $B$.